# Expect script to open a terminal or multiple terminals and send commands to it

Tags: linux, automation, expect

Can i get to know what will be the Expect script to open a terminal or multiple terminals and send commands to it?

I am unable to spawn terminal from it.

I am using Cent OS 7.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: You can launch GUI applications from expect, but you cannot control them. Expect is text-only.

Comment: any alternatives other than expect to do this task ?